# jquery: how to open div from scroll position

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm working on a menu which opened with a floating button. I would like to open the menu from the position i'm in, so i can see the menu. the problem is i can't use css `position: fixed;` because the menu is quite big and requires scrolling the page.

```
    $("#exp_menu").click(function() {
        $("#left_block").show();
        $("#exp_menu_close").show();
        $("#exp_menu").hide();
    });
```

Comment: define: position i'm in. If you mean from the position of your floating button then you must put the menu relative to the button-container. If you mean the actual mouse position, then your menu must be absolute and relative to the body. Then you can get the mouse coordinates per javascript and define them as origin of your menu div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `#exp_menu` element is the "menu" that you are referring to.

You can get the current scroll position in your click event handler and update the position of the `#left_block` element as necessary. If you want to dock the `#left_block` element to the top of the viewport you can use this:

```
$("#exp_menu").click(function() {
    $("#left_block").css({
        top : $(window).scrollTop()
    }).show();
    $("#exp_menu_close").show();
    $("#exp_menu").hide();
});
```

This solution requires that the `#left_block` element is absolutely positioned and its offset parent is the `body` element.

`$(window).scrollTop()` returns the scroll position of the current window: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/